# Как отписаться от Materialdesign события?

Tags: c#, wpf

Возникла проблема с подписками на событие, так как на одно событие повесил 2 разных обработчика, один из обработчиков находится на `Window`, а второй обработчик на `UserControl'e`.

В итоге, что я имею:

(*2 обработчика для разных событий в `Window`*),

```
 <materialDesign:DialogHost DialogOpened="openLB" DialogClosing="closingLB">
```

(*2 обработчика для тех же событий в `UserControl'e`*).

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost DialogOpened="openCB" DialogClosing="closingCB">
```

И из-за этого, получается что идет вызов двух обработчиков для одного события, что вызывает за собой исключение в совершенно другом классе в методе `openLB()`

Код метода:

```
 private async void openLB(object sender, MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.DialogOpenedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        IsLogedIn = await validCreds();

        if (IsLogedIn)
        {
            eventArgs.Session.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            eventArgs.Session.Close(false);
        }
    }
```

На данной строке я ловлю исключение:

```
        else
        {
            eventArgs.Session.Close(false);
        }
```

Само исключение:

[image: exception]

---

То есть выходит такая иерархия вызово события (*принадлежит событию `DialogOpened`*) `openCB()` -> (*принадлежит событию `DialogClosing`*) `closingCB()` -> (*вызов обработчика принадлежащего событию `DialogClosing`*) `closingLB()` -> (*вызов обработчика принадлежащему событию `DialogOpened`*) `openLB()`

Видео с принципом работы прикрепил ниже, так как мог что-то упустить или плохо расписать

Вопрос конечный заключается в том, как отписаться от данных обработчиков и подписываться только при необходимости? Ибо как я понял тут не работает принцип с самописными `event'ами`

[Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LU7u6LLDOjU) для наглядности работы

[Проект](https://github.com/Ezario/Pharmacy_WPF)

Comment: Код выкладывайте текстом.

Comment: @Bulson все недочеты вроде как поисправлял и видео перезалил на новое

Comment: А вам не кажется, что данный вопрос стоит задавать авторам используемой вами библиотеки? Это не чистый WPF, это нестандартная ошибка, о которой многие тут даже не знают и не знают из-за чего она. И тут сейчас получается так, что нам придется за вас идти, читать документацию, разбирать как эта система работает. Так что в этом случае все же первым делом стоит спрашивать у создателей что вы делаете не так, а у нас, хотя бы укажите, что ошибка именно этого ужасного MaterialDesign, а не чистого WPF. Также я не пойму, почему вы не используете привязки? У вас в проекте каша, смесь всего и вся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else
{
    if (eventArgs.Session.IsEnded == false)
    {
         eventArgs.Session.Close(false);
    }
           
}
```